# Python generate sdist and upload it in a separate step

Tags: python, distutils, sdist

I am building several Python packages and would like to upload them only if all the packages have been successfully built. I have a separate stage for each Python package, whose `sdist` is carried to the last stage where all collected `sdist`s should be uploaded (if the build reaches the final stage, then all packages were built successfully).

Now, is there a way to execute `python setup.py sdist`, then `python setup.py upload [path]` in order to achieve what I need? Or is there a better way for this?

P.S.: I am using Bamboo, if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, upload will only push files that are created by a distutils sdist/bdist command run from the same command line than upload, e.g. `python setup.py sdist upload`.  If you run `sdist`, check the result, and then do `sdist upload`, the second sdist should be exactly the same, unless your setup.py is buggy, you made changes to your files or you have a computer problem.  (I agree that’s a lot of unless).

A trick can be used to avoid the second sdist to redo all its work: Fist you run `python setup.py sdist --keep-temp`, then you check the sdist, and to upload you call `python setup.py sdist --dry-run upload`.

There is an open enhancement request to improve this in the next feature release: http://bugs.python.org/issue12944

In the meantime, you can use [twine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine/).

Comment: My sdist mechanism is a little more complex, that's why I needed to do it in one place, and the upload in another place. I don't achieve anything if I do all those complex operations twice. Thought it was another way of doing this which I've missed.

Comment: Edited reply to mention twine.

Comment: Twine seems pretty nice. Thank you!